# How to Import Dirty Excel through c# having data truncation type guessing

Tags: c#, sql-server, excel, import-from-excel

I am importing some dirty excel files having more than 2lac records from sheet using the SQL bulk copy method through C#.

Problems:

1. I am reading the data through an `OleDbDataReader` which has a Type guessing problem in the case of reading excel files using C#. It guesses the datatype of the columns and if a row starts with a datetime value it automatically identifies the containing columns will be  datetime values, and all the other string values on that row are inserted / read by the reader as null.
2. there is also a problem with string values with truncation of 255 char. If some of the values are fewer than 255 characters than it guesses that the containing column will be text rather than memo.

Due to these two problems I'd say that importing data from Excel to SQL Server using C# is not perfect - any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Use something else to import your excel stuff.

http://epplus.codeplex.com/

Comment: Hi Chris, thanks for your reply this solution will not work under all versions of excel.. :(

Answer (score 0):

I know of two approaches for this without using external components.

**ONE**
If you can save the file as CSV before you have to import it, then you can use the text-file driver and the [schema.ini](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms709353%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) file approach, which allows you to explicitly declare data types column by column.

The schema.ini approach also works for the SQL OPENROWSET command allowing you to import directly from CSV to SQL without the need for C# in the middle, whilst still allowing you to specify column data types.

**TWO** If you're not allergic to making registry hacks, here's [Microsoft's suggestion](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/281517).

It suggests making changes to the registry key:

> HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Jet\4.0\Engines\Excel\TypeGuessRows

or for 64 bit systems:

> HKLM\SOFTWARE\wow6432node\microsoft\jet\4.0\engines\excel\TypeGuessRows

By setting this value to zero, the first 16384 lines of your spreadsheet are scanned for type guessing, rather than the default of 8. If any text fields longer than 255 chars are encountered, then those columns are deemed to be memo fields.

Note that you are still not *100% guaranteed* to get the right data types, depending on your data.

Note also the HKLM scope of this key though - it will affect every OleDB Excel import by any process on that machine.

Or, without hacking the registry:

> A second way to work around this problem (without modifying the
>   registry) is to make sure that rows with fields, which have data 255
>   characters or greater, are present in the first 8 rows of the source
>   data file.

which is most likely not possible.

Comment: Hi Neil i have tried all three solutions but could not be able to get rid of these dirty files. i dont know why microsoft only is having these kind of bugs included all the time.

Comment: Bit harsh to call it a bug if a column has more than one type of data in it, I say. How can it _know_ what type is the right type? Failing type guessing, then you're into third-party components. I know of http://exceldatareader.codeplex.com/ (I've never used it) or Aspose.Cells (loads of features, but maybe overkill?)

Comment: How did the CSV + schema.ini solution fail?

Comment: i am not aware of the column schema my application imports data from x table with xExcel file